# Read excel row by row and do transpose, Python 3.6

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have excel file with below data and I want to read data where First Column contains 'Area' & transpose, then again move & find where Column contains 'Area' & transpose

In this data total 3 table data given, I want to split it & then transpose. First Column contains **Area code** and other column name contains **Year**

```
Area    1980    1981    1982    1983
AU  33.7    38.8    40.2    42.5
BE  54.6    51.6    49.7    48.9
FI  43.2    49.6    58.8    71.1
Area    1979    1980    1981    1982
AU  29.8    33.7    38.8    40.2
BE  54.2    54.6    51.6    49.7
CA  39.4    44.3    50.6    48
Area    1978    1979    1980    1981
DK  58  57.2    54.5    53.2
FI  37.7    43.2    49.6    58.8
FR  41.6    49.9    55.4    58.5
```

Final Result expected:

```
Area    variable    value
AU  1980    33.7
other values
```

How to achieve this?

Comment: Refer to [stack](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html#pandas.DataFrame.stack) function in data frame.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that we have the following list of DataFrame's:

```
In [106]: dfs
Out[106]:
[  Area  1980  1981  1982  1983
 0   AU  33.7  38.8  40.2  42.5
 1   BE  54.6  51.6  49.7  48.9
 2   FI  43.2  49.6  58.8  71.1,   Area  1979  1980  1981  1982
 0   AU  29.8  33.7  38.8  40.2
 1   BE  54.2  54.6  51.6  49.7
 2   CA  39.4  44.3  50.6  48.0,   Area  1978  1979  1980  1981
 0   DK  58.0  57.2  54.5  53.2
 1   FI  37.7  43.2  49.6  58.8
 2   FR  41.6  49.9  55.4  58.5]
```

first we concatenate them horizontally:

```
In [107]: df = pd.concat([x.set_index('Area') for x in dfs], axis=1)

In [108]: df
Out[108]:
    1980  1981  1982  1983  1979  1980  1981  1982  1978  1979  1980  1981
AU  33.7  38.8  40.2  42.5  29.8  33.7  38.8  40.2   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
BE  54.6  51.6  49.7  48.9  54.2  54.6  51.6  49.7   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
CA   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  39.4  44.3  50.6  48.0   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
DK   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  58.0  57.2  54.5  53.2
FI  43.2  49.6  58.8  71.1   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  37.7  43.2  49.6  58.8
FR   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  41.6  49.9  55.4  58.5
```

now we can stack DF and rename columns:

```
In [109]: df.stack().reset_index() \
            .rename(columns={'level_0':'Area','level_1':'variable',0:'value'})
Out[109]:
   Area variable  value
0    AU     1980   33.7
1    AU     1981   38.8
2    AU     1982   40.2
3    AU     1983   42.5
4    AU     1979   29.8
5    AU     1980   33.7
6    AU     1981   38.8
7    AU     1982   40.2
8    BE     1980   54.6
9    BE     1981   51.6
10   BE     1982   49.7
11   BE     1983   48.9
12   BE     1979   54.2
13   BE     1980   54.6
14   BE     1981   51.6
15   BE     1982   49.7
16   CA     1979   39.4
17   CA     1980   44.3
18   CA     1981   50.6
19   CA     1982   48.0
20   DK     1978   58.0
21   DK     1979   57.2
22   DK     1980   54.5
23   DK     1981   53.2
24   FI     1980   43.2
25   FI     1981   49.6
26   FI     1982   58.8
27   FI     1983   71.1
28   FI     1978   37.7
29   FI     1979   43.2
30   FI     1980   49.6
31   FI     1981   58.8
32   FR     1978   41.6
33   FR     1979   49.9
34   FR     1980   55.4
35   FR     1981   58.5
```

Answer (score 0):

what have you tried thus far? 
Pandas is a really good library to use for data parsing etc.
you could implement something along the lines of...

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame.from_csv(csv_filename)
def create_new_table(df):
    start = 0
    end = 3
    while (df.last_valid_index() != end):
       #create a new dataframe with the relevant column
       newdf.transpose()
       start = end
       end = end + 3
```

Comment: thanks for response, I did not tried as I was not sure these  can be implemented. I got some files to read data, so working on the same. as of now I have done mannually